# Regex for palindromes accepts non-palindrome 3-letters words

Tags: regex, bash, regex-group, palindrome

My regex should accept every palindrome for word length from 2 to 7 letters (without whitespaces).
My regex looks like this:

```
^(\S?)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$
```

Can you explain to me what I did wrong during writing that regex and how can I fix it?

For me looks fine except one thing: it accepts words like: poj, kip, ret etc. I think its connected
with the middle question mark but I'm not convinced.

Comment: I cannot reproduce https://regex101.com/r/EXptM6/1 It seems that words like `poj`, `kip` etc are rejected.

Comment: In your Bash version, `\S` might not be supported, use `[^[:space:]]` instead. Also, define it in a variable, `rx='^([^[:space:]]?)([^[:space:]]?)([^[:space:]]?)[^[:space:]]?\3\2\1$'`, and then use `if [[ "$string" =~ $rx ]]; then ...`

Comment: Whoa... I got a segmentation fault from bash when trying out `re='(\S?)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$'`  (note the missing `^` at the start). :-)

Comment: I get `re='^(\S?)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1'` to work, but as soon as I add the `$` anchor, it matches those 3 OP mentioned too.

Comment: If guys say so, I'd like to ask you for one more thing. Can you make a simple text file which contains words: abba, aaa, cac, abbba, abc (every word in new line) and then use  command: grep -Ec "^(\S?)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$" on that file? Even tho some of you say that the 3-letters non-palindrome words are rejected the output gives 5 (the correct number is 4).

Comment: @MemberofPepper I've tried your command: With `grep -Ec "^(\S?)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$" file.txt` I'm getting 1. Using `grep (GNU grep) 3.4`

Comment: @MemberofPepper After converting the newlines to Unix-style newlines and using the `grep -Ec '^(\S)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$' a.txt` (note the `\S` at the beginning) I'm getting 4.

Comment: please update the question with the additional details and sample code attempts, along with the (wrong) output generated by the code the and the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, `^(\S?)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$` matches `poj`, `kip` and `ret` by capturing empty in the capture groups. Disclaimer: I'm not 100% sure this is the correct conclusion.

In order to mandate at least 2 characters, make the first capture mandatory:
`^(\S)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$`.

Example:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

teststrs=('aa' 'abccba' 'abba' 'abcba' 'abcdcba' 'abcdcbaaaaa'
          'ab' 'abc cba' 'poj' 'kip' 'ret')

re='^(\S)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$'

for str in "${teststrs[@]}"
do
    if [[ "$str" =~ $re ]]; then
        echo "$str matches"
    fi
done
```

Output:

```
aa matches
abccba matches
abba matches
abcba matches
abcdcba matches
```

You'll get a similar result for `grep -E '^(\S)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$'`, given this input:

```
aa
abccba
abba
abcba
abcdcba
abcdcbaaaaa
ab
abca
abc cba
poj
kip
ret
```

You'll get this:

```
aa
abccba
abba
abcba
abcdcba
```

If you instead use your original, `grep -E '^(\S?)(\S?)(\S?)\S?\3\2\1$'`, you'll get the three letter matches you talked about too, but using the `grep --color` option shows no actual matches on the four last ones:

```
aa
abccba
abba
abcba
abcdcba
abca
poj
kip
ret
```

Comment: Fully understandable. Thank you but would you like to do my exercise from my comment below main post? The one with using grep through file.

Comment: @MemberofPepper Oh, ok. I concentrated on bash regex since that's what you asked about. I won't get back to the computer in a few hours tovtest it with `grep`.

Comment: @MemberofPepper Updated with my `grep` findings.